# Recovering zfs pool

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have a zfs pool setup on my ubuntu 20.04 system.  I had 4 drives and decided to replace 1 of them for a larger one.  I tried to offline the drive, then powered off, replaced with new drive, powered on and now my pool is unavailable and the drive ID '/dev/sdd' is marked faulted.  I cannot import the pool as it says no pools found.  lsblk shows all the drives, the 3 original with the new one and the new one is labeled as '/dev/sdd'.  They system still displays my pool name but says one or more devices is currently unavailable.

How can i remove the '/dev/sdd' from the pool so it will show the pool is available?

Any ideas?
Please and thank you!

zpool import -a among other variations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with:

zpool replace pool_name /dev/sdd /dev/newdisk

What was the configuration of the pool? If RAID0 you will not recover anything.
You should connect old drive, replace it with command above and wait until it finish. Only then you can remove it.

Please post:

zpool status -v

zpool import

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."